# convert array to List using ArrayList's constructor

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm aware that I could convert an array to List using Arrays.asList() function. But the source code shows that it calls ArrayList's constructor.

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

Why I cannot call it directly?

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(str.split(" "));
```

This will end up with "no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(java.lang.String[])"

Comment: `java.util.ArrayList != java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`

Comment: @Lino Yeah, I got it, Thanks